# Java // Array // Multiplication // For-loop;

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, rotational-matrices

**Objective:** Produce rotation using the rotation matrix;

```
private double[][] rotateX = {{1.00,0.00,0.00},{0.00,Math.cos(theta),Math.sin(-theta)},{0.00,Math.sin(theta),Math.cos(theta)}};   // Rotation matrice for x axis;
```

**Problem definition:** Output does not match the expectation;

**Expected output:**

```
newX = 3
newY = -2.236 
newZ = -0.002
// Checked in MathCAD;
```

**Output produced:**

```
newX = 3.00
newY =-2.00
newZ = 1.0000000000000002
```

**Code applied:**

```
public class Test2 {
private double[] target = {3.00,1.00,2.00};        // target data for matrix multiplication;
private double[] product = {0.00,0.00,0.00};       // product of the for-loop;

private double theta = Math.toRadians(90.00);      // Rotation angle;

private double[][] rotateX = {{1.00,0.00,0.00},
        {0.00,Math.cos(theta),Math.sin(-theta)},
        {0.00,Math.sin(theta),Math.cos(theta)}};   // Rotation matrice for x axis;

private void rotateAroundX(){
    double temp;                                  // temp. data storage;

    double newX = 0.00;                           // new x after for-loop;
    double newY = 0.00;                           // new y after for-loop;
    double newZ = 0.00;                           // new z after for-loop;

    for(int i = 0; i < rotateX.length ; i ++){          // check how many items are stored in the matrix;
        for(int j = 0; j < rotateX[i].length; j++){     // check how many elements are stored in each item;

            temp = rotateX[i][j] * target[j];           // store product of the multiplication in temp;

            if(i == 0){
                newX += temp;                           // if i index is 0 finalize matrix multiplication and set newX; Ex. 1 row of rotateX - (1.00*3.00 + 0.00*1.00 + 0.00*2.00); 
            }
            if(i == 1){                                 // if i index is 1 finalize matrix multiplication and set newY;
                newY += temp;
            }
            if(i == 2){                                 // if i index is 2 finalize matrix multiplication and set newZ;
                newZ += temp;
            }
        }
    }

    this.product[0] = newX;                             // Add newX to product;
    this.product[1] = newY;                             // Add newY to product;
    this.product[2] = newZ;                             // Add newZ to product;                 

}

public void sart(){
    rotateAroundX();                   // run test-case;

    for (double e : product){
        System.out.println(e);         // output the product information;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What did you discover when you stepped through this with a debugger?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - nothing the process flow is as expected, however the output differs from what I'd expect basing my believe on the MathCAD results.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is a bit strange, but simple: your expected output is wrong. To me your produced output seems right.

Answer (score 0):

You are using radians whereas in your expected output you are using degrees.

Changing

```
private double theta = Math.toRadians(90.00);
```

to:

```
private double theta = 90;
```

gives you expected output.

Comment: that gives me a confusion , because that documentation states that the input for cos() / sin() / tan() functions must be in radians;

Comment: Maybe your expected output is not calculated correctly, as you are right, the Math trigonometric functions use radians, I just tried it. Did you perhaps think that the method you used for your expected output uses degrees, but in fact it used radians?

Comment: I've read documentation for MathCAD. @EdgarBoda you are right. The problem was in the approach used to calculate the expected result. Please add your answer and I will vote it as the correct answer.